# contentsOfDirectory returns three files, enumerator returns none

Tags: ios, swift

Can anyone see what I did wrong here? `everything` has three files, the `enumerator` has none and exits on the first `.nextObject`:

```
    let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    let everything = try! FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: documentsURL, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: [])
    let keys = [URLResourceKey.isRegularFileKey, URLResourceKey.localizedNameKey]
    let options: FileManager.DirectoryEnumerationOptions = [.skipsPackageDescendants, .skipsSubdirectoryDescendants, .skipsHiddenFiles]
    let enumerator = FileManager.default.enumerator(
        at: documentsURL,
        includingPropertiesForKeys: keys,
        options: options,
        errorHandler: {(url, error) -> Bool in
            return true
    })
    if enumerator != nil {
        while let fileURL = enumerator!.nextObject() {
            // ...
        }
    }
```

Comment: What are the 3 files in `everything`?

Comment: Three images, as I expect.

Comment: I have no clue, either.

Comment: Do the filenames begin with a `.`?

Comment: No, they are like image_biglongnumber.jpg

Comment: Just wondering, Did you try calling `enumerator` without the keys and the options as you did for the `contentsOfDirectory`?

Comment: Could it be that the directory you're working from is one level higher than you intended ? contentsOfDirectory() is probably recursing down while the enumerator does not

Comment: Ahh, that is definitely something to test...